# Are there any Javascript (Node) template engines that have IDE support for view-models?

Tags: javascript, templates, view, typescript, template-engine

We are evaluating Typescript + Node as a possible alternative to PHP.

Typescript is particularly attractive to us because of the excellent, consistent editor/IDE support - my biggest problem with recommending this at the moment, is that views (templates) do not seem to receive any real IDE support. That is, I haven't been able to find a JS template engine with proper IDE support - and by "proper", I mean auto-completion and inspections for a view-model.

Our current approach in PHP for views is something along the lines of this:

```
<?php /** @var OrderFormView $view */ ?>
<div class="order-form">
   ...
   <div class="order-total"><?= $view->total ?></div>
   ...
</div>
```

In an editor like PhpStorm, the type-hint at the beginning of each view file provides auto-completion for `$view` and design-time inspections for expressions like `$view->total` - this works really well in a fairly large team, where e.g. juniors can work with view-models without having to drill through code, as opposed to using an untyped view-dictionary.

Now with Typescript/Javascript, we need an equivalent (server-side) approach - the language support for Typescript in e.g. JetBrains IDEs and ATOM.IO is superb, but we haven't found anything that provides the same degree of support for views. Our solutions are heavy on presentation, so having good design-time support for views is important so we can move fast.

Our best option that we know of at the moment,  is simple string-templates in Typescript, e.g.:

```
module view {

    interface OrderFormView {
        total: number;
        // ...
    }

    export function order_form(view: OrderFormView) {
        return `
<div class="order-form">
   ...
   <div class="order-total">${ view.total }</div>
   ...
</div>
`;
    }

}
```

This would work, and would provide the level of IDE support we need, but doesn't look very nice with the weird indentation etc.

Are there any Javascript (server-side, e.g. Node) template engines that could deliver what we're looking for?

EDIT: Alternatively, a template engine that uses plain HTML and a DSL of sorts to bind models to the HTML, along the lines of [queryTemplates](http://code.google.com/p/querytemplates/) but hopefully more modern.

EDIT: Nope. Separating the data-binding (JS) from the actual template (HTML) leads to close coupling between the binding code and the actual template - our templates have to be easy to replace, so this approach won't work. The solution has to involve view-models, that much I'm sure of - and the templates must be able to stand alone, that's a given. And it has to provide IDE support with checking/auto-completion for the view-model. The only thing known to me that meets those requirements is PHP. I guess it had to be good for something after all ;-)

Comment: Knockout.js is a pretty interesting MVVM framework for JavaScript.

Comment: On the server side? And with auto-complete for view-models? In which editor/IDE?

Comment: Does it need to be server-side?

Comment: Yes - I thought that was clear since we're looking for the equivalent of PHP templates :-)

Comment: Why are you stuck on using a PHP template approach for a different language/platform?  WebStorm provides some auto-complete functionality for JS.  I don't see why there would be a difference if it was server- or client-side.

Comment: Alright, suggest a different approach then? (the main reason I look for an embedded template syntax, is so our 20 or so devs can feel at home - I'm not married to that approach at all, but it has to provide IDE support)

Comment: Current thinking: something like ye olde [queryTemplates](http://code.google.com/p/querytemplates/) - using plain HTML (with IDE support, obviously) combined with type-safe TS implementing the actual binding of the model to the HTML template. This library is old and unmaintained though. May have to rewrite it in TS myself...